# How can one create smooth edged spotlights in OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl, lighting

I am currently working on implementing lighting to my project with OpenGL. Still working on the basic implementation (getting lights to display correctly) and I encountered a weird problem. When trying to create a spotlight with a cutoff (limited angle affected by the light) I get very hard edges, almost like stairs, as seen in this picture:

There is no ambient light (using `glLightModel(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, colorToFloatBuffer(new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)))`) and I also disabled spot exponent (specifies how the light is distributed in the cone) and all attenuations to make the effect clearer and the background is a big white image (made black by the lack of ambient light; I am also wondering why I even need ot use an image at all in order to see the light).

[image: Weird light]

Here is how I set up the light:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

glLight(glLightID, GL_AMBIENT, colorToFloatBuffer(Color.blue));
glLight(glLightID, GL_DIFFUSE, colorToFloatBuffer(Color.black));
glLight(glLightID, GL_SPECULAR, colorToFloatBuffer(Color.black));

glLight(glLightID, GL_POSITION, floatBuffer.put(position.x).put(position.y).put(0.0f).put(1.0f));

glLight(glLightID, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, otherFloatBuffer.put(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); 
glLightf(glLightID, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 0);
glLightf(glLightID, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 22.5f);

glLightf(glLightID, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.0f);
glLightf(glLightID, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
glLightf(glLightID, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
```

On a different note, I also scale the context before applying any of these effects (I use perspective view for some visual effects and yet want to maintain orthographic coordinates), if that is any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are to ways you can achieve that:

1. Continue using per-vertex lighting. You, however, should increase the resolution of your scene - put more polygons inside!
2. Change to per-pixel lighting. You will need to learn shader programs. [Here are some tutorials on the topic](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/spot-light-per-pixel/).

Comment: Had I only known this 5 days ago ;) It took a surprisingly long time to figure that one out and understand how it is vertex based.. now I understand. The tutorial you linked is actually *really* really good, I have been using it to and it (almost) fully works now.